# IEEE Referencing: Same source, different page numbers

Tags: citations, writing, writing-style

I'm fairly new to IEEE referencing and have a slight dilemma.
If I'm going to be citing the same paper twice in my writing but want to cite specific pages of it, do I include the source twice in the reference list or is there a different way round this?
***For example:***

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 100 [1], consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vestibulum nunc nec velit iaculis viverra [2].

**References:**

[1] M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Eds., Handbook of Mathematical Functions (Applied Mathematics Series 55).
Washington, DC: NBS, 1964, pp. 32-33.

[2] M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Eds., Handbook of Mathematical Functions (Applied Mathematics Series 55).
Washington, DC: NBS, 1964, pp. 84-86.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you include a source only once in the reference list. If you have to refer to a specific part of a source, you do it in the in-text citation, not the reference list, as in one of these examples:

> [3, Th. 1]; [3, Lemma 2]; [3, pp. 5-10]; [3, eq. (2)]; [3, Fig. 1]; [3, Appendix I]; [3, Sec. 4.5]; [3, Ch. 2, pp. 5-10];
>   [3, Algorithm 5].

Source: [IEEE Editorial Style Manual (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325015653if_/https://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf)